# What's the etymology of 점심 (點心) meaning 'lunch'?

Tags: etymology, hanja

The characters for 점심 (點心) mean something like:

**點** - 'point' or 'dot'
**心** - 'heart'

Those characters have other meanings too, but I can't see from any of them how the characters come to make a word that means 'lunch'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perhaps better asked at Chinese StackExchange, but from what I can gather, it is a slang word that first appeared in the Tang Dynasty. E.g.:

> 舊唐書:「夫人謂其弟曰：『治妝未畢，我未及餐，爾且可**點心**。』」
>
> 夫人 (someone's wife) said to her younger brother: "I haven't finished doing my makeup, and am not ready to dine, you can **點心**."

My interpretation is that 點 means something similar to *light up/excite*, e.g. 點火/점화 (*to ignite something*) or 點香 (*to light/burn incense*), so 點心 means to light up the heart -> satisfy one's cravings.

Note that in Chinese, 點心 means *snack*, and is the word used for the tapas-like food in the Cantonese Yum Cha tradition *Dim Sum*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did see if there was already a question about  點心 on Chinese SE, but ultimately it's the Korean word '점심' I care about, which I can't really ask about on Chinese.SE. Anyway, meta question: [What questions should be asked on Chinese.SE instead of here?](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/what-questions-should-be-asked-on-chinese-se-instead-of-here)

Answer (score 0):

점심 (點心 =putting a point in heart)

1.하루 중에 해가 가장 높이 떠 있는, 정오부터 반나절쯤까지의 동안.
from 12 to 1 pm.

> 2. 끼니로 먹는 음식. 또는 끼니를 먹는 일. food or eating food.

**추가 설명 additional explanation :**

동양 사상에는 아침은 제대로 먹고 점심 저녁은 가볍게 서양 사상에는
아침과 점심은 가볍게

저녁은 만찬이라해서 푸짐하게 먹는 습관이
있습니다.

In eastern philosophy we eat breakfast enough but lunch and supper a
little.

But in western, we eat breakfast and lunch a little but supper
enough, since it is a feast.

동양에서나 서양에서나 점심은 가볍게 먹는 습관을 가졌습니다.

That is, in both, lunch is to eat a little.

그래서 생겨난 말이 점심, 즉 점을 찍듯이 가볍게

먹는 음식이라는
뜻으로 사용하는 말이 되었답니다.

Therefor, we use 점심 for a word whose means eating a little like
putting a point.